# Get input form data posted by users

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to develop a plugin but I'm stuck at a point where I want to access the already existed form input values. Is there a way for my plugin to get any input form data posted by users?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to utilize the `$_POST` super global variable. For example, if the form had a field named `post-text`, you could access the posted data at `$_POST[ 'post-text' ]`. Of course, you'd want to sanitize it properly before using it.

Comment: $_POST is not available everywhere, it can be accessed only on the action page of the form

Comment: I answered the question you posted. Please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/264290/edit) your question and provide details about what you are trying to do.